# Upgrade preloaded SQLITE Database without losing the record from another table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to delete one table and upgrade it. I used DB Browser for SQLITE, so it is preloaded database, I don't used create table...

My question is, how do I upgrade the preloaded SQLITE Database without losing the record from another table?

These are my database table,

1. Promos
2. Favorites
3. Users

I want to delete the "Users", and upgrade the sqlite database without losing the data of "Promos" and "Favorites"

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Database.db";
    private static final int DB_VER = 7;

    Context context;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post the database content for better understing the issue.

Comment: edited. thanks for replying :)

Comment: have you loaded your DB from assets folder?

Comment: yes @MJM and heres the code, check edited